# How can i add mdf database to Ms sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have given asp.net membership provider security into my web application for login and created database into the ms sql server all working fine on local server but, when I transfer my database local machine to server login credential is not working. I am guessing its happen because, I have used asp.net membership security and it has created .mdf file in my app code file, can any help me please now how can, I add this .mdf database into my Ms sql database...?????

Answer (score 1):

Google for Attach Database.  An mdf is a detached database image and can be copied, reattached ...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to detach/attach a database. You may need both, mdf and ldf files. You should also transfer logins between servers. See [how-to here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546).